# Role based access in MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, role-base-authorization

I'm developing Intranet web application using MVC 4 Razor (Windows based authentication).
I would like to get guidance to correct approach to implement the following scenario.

My application has 2 Roles - HR and Manager.

I have a View which has a radio control that displays the Employee Type. Following are the values.
1. Temporary
2. Permanent
3. Intern
4. Consultant

Both HR and Manager role users have access to the above View. But the requirement - HR should see "Permanent" and "Intern" value, whereas Manager should see "Temporary" and "Consultant" value in that Radio control.

The above 4 values are coming from Database table.

I would like authorize the user based on the role and its access to the Htmlcontrol and Htmlcontrol(radio button) binding data.

I would prefer to use a generic way to handle this scenario, instead of filtering the data based on the role using if condition in view.

Please guide me the approach that I need to use to well handle this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach I can think of is,

you create

**public class RoleManagerFilter : ActionFilterAttribute**

and in this class you add, following function

**void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)**

the above function will check the role from session(assuming its in session)
and then accordingly filter the data for Employee Type

here is the msdn link for the theory behind it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I have used IActionFilter.OnResultExecuting function to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can start with implementing **Forms authentication** in your
   application.
2. Store the user's role inside the encrypted forms ticket on login &
   inside your controller decrypt it to get the user role & pass it to
   your Data access repository.
3. There you fetch relevant fields depending upon the role of currently
   logged in user & pass it to your view. This will get you started [A
   beginner's tutorial on Forms Authentication (Code Project)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF)

This will work for as many users you add in future provided you have role based values defined in your database.